# Search Increasing URL For Text - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I've got a Node.js script which searches through an increasing URL to see if a user has a certain item in the inventory. If they do, it displays their userid.

Here's the script:

```
// Import the scraping libraries
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

// Array for the user IDs which match the query
var matches = [];

// Do this for all possible users
function makeRequest(i){
    var location = "http://www.roblox.com/Trade/inventoryhandler.ashx?filter=0&userid=" + i + "&page=1&itemsPerPage=14";

    request(location, function (error, response, body) {

        console.log('request made for id '+ i);
        if (!error) {

            // Load the website content
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var bodyText = $("body").text();

            // Search the website content for gaming
            if (bodyText.indexOf("gaming") > -1) {

                console.log("Found gaming in inventory of user ", i);
                // Save the user ID, if gaming was found
                matches.push(i);
            }

        // Something goes wrong
        } else {

            console.log(error.message);
        }

        if(i==261){
            console.log("All users with gaming in inventory: ", matches);

            return;
        }

        makeRequest(i+1); 
    });
}

makeRequest(1);
```

The link http://www.roblox.com/Trade/inventoryhandler.ashx?filter=0&userid=261&page=1&itemsPerPage=14 has the text 'gaming' on it, however it returns with no results after being executed.

Can you help me identify the issue with the script, so it will display the userids of those who have gaming in their inventory?

Comment: The link you provided returns an empty response for me.

Comment: It shouldn't do.. here's a screenshot of it: http://prntscr.com/9898xb

Comment: Can you `curl` the URL yourself to see whether data is returned _outside the browser_? An empty response for us other people sounds to me like an authentication problem... and that could be a reason why your script is failing.